# Why did I get a blue screen of death after loading the game Fall Guys?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I was loading a game called Fall Guys, and suddenly the blue screen of death popped up. This has never happened before.

I’ve also tried opening other games and they work fine. I open the the log from the minidump but I dont know what to do with it. Heres the report.

Can someone tell what the problem with it. Is it possible it has something to do with the game anti cheat software?

```
Dump File : 071922-60515-01.dmp
Crash Time : 7/19/2022 11:20:06 PM
Bug Check String :
Bug Check Code : 0x00000139
Parameter 1 : 00000000`00000003
Parameter 2 : fffffa81`ab2f6600
Parameter 3 : fffffa81`ab2f6558
Parameter 4 : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver : dxgmms2.sys
Caused By Address : dxgmms2.sys+183df
File Description :
Product Name :
Company :
File Version :
Processor : x64
Crash Address : ntoskrnl.exe+1c3e40
Stack Address 1 :
Stack Address 2 :
Stack Address 3 :
Computer Name :
Full Path : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\071922-60515-01.dmp
Processors Count : 4
Major Version : 15
Minor Version : 18362
Dump File Size : 1,600,338
Dump File Time : 7/19/2022 11:22:21 PM
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x139--kernel-security-check-failure

Comment: Please edit your question to add details on your PC make and mode: I am a macOS person, but the “Caused By Driver” shows `dxgmms2.sys` and a Google search comes up with [this page](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-fix-the-dxgmms2-sys-bsod-error-in-windows-10/): **“The ‘dxgmms2.sys’ blue screen of death (BSOD) error occurs when the DirectX Graphics MMS system file in Windows 10 crashes due to outdated, buggy, or broken graphics card drivers. But rarely, general file corruption and memory-related faults can also contribute to the issue.”** Seems like a graphic drive issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here is the dropbox link to the minidump files for better details, https://www.dropbox.com/s/88bbpjc878m4nyb/Minidump.rar?dl=0
inform  me if theres a problem with the link or the file